# SQL Weird Conversion of char data type to a datetime data type error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this query that runs fine:

```
SELECT 
Value
    FROM data
    WHERE MetaDataID = 'f249819e-817f-4be5-bee9-21aa3d7f72e6'
```

which returns:

```
27/6/2011 19:12:28
11/7/2011 19:18:54
10/7/2011 11:49:35
3/7/2011 17:41:53
```

if I Alter the query to:

```
SELECT 
VALUE,
MONTH(Value)
    FROM data  
    WHERE MetaDataID = 'f249819e-817f-4be5-bee9-21aa3d7f72e6'
```

I get the error: The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Info that might help:

1) The Value Column is VARCHAR type.

2) WHEN I specify the MetaDataId, I make sure the result is "date". to make sure, I've used WHERE IsDate(Value) = 1 too and also I've used ISDATe(Value) on the select to see if every result was a date and it was...

I don't known why this is hapenning... Anybody have a clue?

Comment: Are the server and client both in the same localisation - is your SQL server running as e.g. US English where 27 would be parsed as the month number?

Comment: yes same location and month is parsed as number

Comment: This is why, *if* I'm going to support arbitrary data storage such as this, I include columns of appropriate types, rather than converting everything to/from varchars (I'd usually also include appropriate keys and checks, so that if the metadata is meant to be a date, only the date column can be populated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to perform an explicit conversion to a `datetime` datatype.

```
SELECT 
VALUE,
MONTH(Convert(DateTime, Value,103)) as [Month]
    FROM data  
    WHERE MetaDataID = 'f249819e-817f-4be5-bee9-21aa3d7f72e6'
```

Comment: Didn't realize the issue with the `dd/mm/yy` format not being handled by `CAST`, nice